# Assistance for understanding Qthread and Signals. (Pyside)

Tags: python, pyside, qthread

i am trying to understand how to do a Qthread and i have this skeletal code. my main objective is to not let the GUI "hang" while the backend is doing some database stuff and at the same time updating a table widget in the GUI.
background: Doing this on Windows OS. Pyside as the GUI. (I also tried Python threading, but everytime my application crashes)

```
class GenericThread(QtCore.QThread):
    def __init__(self, function, *args, **kwargs):
        QtCore.QThread.__init__(self)
        self.function = function
        self.args = args
        self.kwargs = kwargs

    def __del__(self):
        self.wait()

    def run(self):
        self.function(*self.args,**self.kwargs)
        return

clas myMainGUI(...)
     def add(self):
         ...
         for myfiles in os.listdir(..): <--- intensive process, lots of files
             column headers = [ .... ]
             result = select_data_from_file(myfiles)  <----- database file processing
             self.insert_table_widget ( column headers, result )  <--want to insert to widge in "realtime" and do other stuff without GUI getting "hang"
             ....
             self.mythread.emit()   <-- ??

     def coolie(self): # some button will call this function.
         if buttonclick == "add": 
            self.mythread = GenericThread(self.add)
            self.mythread.disconnect() <------??
            self.mythread.connect()  <------ ??
            self.mythread.start()
```

any idea how should my emit(), connect() or disconnect() be? thanks

Comment: Do *not* implement `__del__` if you don't know exactly what you are doing. In this case I believe your implementation of `__del__` may cause memory leaks(if not other problems).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest against using threads in parallel with your GUI, unless you are doing some I/O or the library you are using releases the GIL. They will just slow things down.

Either stick with the serial approach, things will get done faster than your current implementation (in an application of mine, I nearly got 2x faster by disposing with threads). And follow python speed up tips like [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonSpeed/PerformanceTips).

You could otherwise use the `multiprocessing` module instead.